# python получить url

Tags: python, post, flask

Подкажите, как получить `url` страницы с которой был произведен `POST` запрос? Например, на странице `localhost/user/user_id=10` есть блок `(form action="add_coment" method="post")` который оставляет комментарий, после чего хочется вернуться на эту же страницу перезагрузив её.
`request.args.get('user_id')` - не подходит, тк это пост запрос, `request.base_url` - уже будет `localhost/add_comment`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. Свойство `request.referrer` хранит данную информацию.